# GitHub actions not passing env vars to Vite build

Tags: reactjs, docker, environment-variables, github-actions, vite

I have the following custom GitHub action below:

```
name: Build App
on:
  workflow_dispatch:

env:
  REGISTRY: ghcr.io
  IMAGE_NAME: ${{ github.repository }}

jobs:
  build-and-push-image:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    permissions:
      contents: read
      packages: write

    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Log in to the Container registry
        uses: docker/login-action@v2
        with:
          registry: ${{ env.REGISTRY }}
          username: ${{ github.actor }}
          password: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}

      - name: Set up Docker Buildx
        uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v2

      - name: Extract metadata (tags, labels) for Docker
        id: meta
        uses: docker/metadata-action@v4
        with:
          images: ${{ env.REGISTRY }}/${{ env.IMAGE_NAME }}
          tags: |
            type=raw,value={{branch}}-{{sha}}-${{env.GITHUB_RUN_NUMBER}}
            type=raw,value=${{ inputs.deploy_target }}
            type=raw,value=latest

      - name: Build and push Docker image
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v4
        with:
          context: .
          push: true
          tags: ${{ steps.meta.outputs.tags }}
          labels: ${{ steps.meta.outputs.labels }}
          cache-from: type=gha
          cache-to: type=gha,mode=max

  deploy:
    needs: build-and-push-image
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    if: ${{ inputs.perform_deploy }}
    steps:
      - name: Run command on remote server
        uses: D3rHase/ssh-command-action@v0.2.2
        env:
          VITE_APP_LOGIN: ${{ vars.SW_APP_LOGIN }} 
          VITE_APP_PASSWORD: ${{ vars.SW_APP_PASSWORD }}
          VITE_APP_EXCLUDE_URLS: ${{ vars.SW_APP_EXCLUDE_URLS }}
        with:
          host: ${{vars.SSH_HOST_APP1}}
          port: ${{vars.SSH_PORT_APP1}}
          user: ${{vars.SSH_USER_APP1}}
          private_key: ${{secrets.SSH_PRIVATE_KEY}}
          command: |
            echo ${{ secrets.DOCKER_TOKEN }} | docker login ghcr.io -u ${{ vars.DOCKER_USER }} --password-stdin;
            docker pull ${{ inputs.deploy_target }};
            docker stop ${{ inputs.deploy_target }};
            docker rm ${{ inputs.deploy_target }};
            docker run --name ${{ inputs.deploy_target }} --env VITE_APP_LOGIN="${{ vars.APP_LOGIN }}" --env VITE_APP_PASSWORD="${{ secrets.APP_PASSWORD }}" -d -p ${{ inputs.deploy_port }}:80
            docker image prune -a --force;
```

In my application, according to the official documentation https://vitejs.dev/guide/env-and-mode, environment variables are declared using `const LOGIN = import.meta.env.LOGIN` However, they accept the value undefined after deployment.

That is, here's how it works:

1. The application performs the installation of dependencies, and build
2. Deployment
3. Runs on a remote server, but with a large number of

   errors, due to the lack of adequate variable values

Comment: What do you mean by "disappear after deployment"? the values are of value `undefined` in run time?

Comment: I apologize for the inappropriate expression. Yes, they accept the value undefined

Comment: You're only passing in those env vars at _run_ time - you haven't shared any information about exactly how you're building and serving the Vite app, but generally those things are baked in at _build_ time (which can be a problem for reasons I expand on [here](https://blog.jonrshar.pe/2020/Sep/19/spa-config.html)).

Comment: I "as described in the documentation" have a.env file, and the variables set as above.

Comment: Can you verify you have configured Action Variables in GitHub dashboard? For example a variable called `APP_LOGIN`

Comment: Yes, that's what the docs say. But again those are looked up _at build time_, but you're only passing them when you _run_ the container (which is presumably just a file server, but without a [mre] who knows).

Comment: @TalRofe Yes, I completely made sure that the github environment variables are fully working, but my app doesn't see them